# Liferay - JAX-RS access forgot password

Tags: security, liferay, liferay-7

I have developed JAX-RX using liferay rest module and it is working fine with oauth.
I am using that rest for mobile usage.
I want use forgot password functionality in mobile and from that I want call rest service.
How can I call rest service for forgot password without token?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. the token is an essential security feature and it needs to exist. Work around to remove the token might get you in a bad situation where the legitimacy of the client is put in check, even during a session. XSS comes to mind.

Comment: How can I implement forgot password fuctionality in mobile using rest api in liferay?

Comment: This is a really broad question you are making. It should be implemented already though, out of the box. What I can tell you if you do decide to implement your own, please keep the token. You can google around, there are ways you can generate those guys using Liferay provided methods.

Comment: How can I use inbuilt forgot password api in mobile?